# How can I log request POST body in Flask?

Tags: python, logging, flask

I'm using flask server, and I want to log each request data and header (so I can use it afterwards to test my server).
I took the werkzeug logger with

```
    self._app.log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
    self._app.log.addHandler(RotatingFileHandler('log.txt', mode='w'))
    self._app.log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

But I don't understand how to change the log format to include request.data and request.headers, all I have is the default log

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [17/Feb/2015 17:09:43] "POST /helloworld HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can log additional info for each request with a [`Flask.before_request` hook](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/api/#flask.Flask.before_request):

```
@app.before_request
def log_request_info():
    app.logger.debug('Headers: %s', request.headers)
    app.logger.debug('Body: %s', request.get_data())
```

This uses the *preconfigured* logger that comes with Flask, [`app.logger`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/logging/).

Comment: When implementing this solution, please be aware that this logs every request, including login and registration endpoints. You'll log user's passwords in plain text if frontend sends it in plaintext.

Comment: If you only want to log information for requests sent to certain endpoint(s), you can use `request.endpoint` within the function to change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create a small helper method, which you call in each and every controller of your flask application.

The helper method will be something like this:

```
def log_my_request_data(request_data):
   #this method will log this data
```

and then in all controllers, get the request.data like this

```
from flask import request

request_data = request.data
```

and call `log_my_request_data(request_data)`